# Como alterar propriedades da fonte em javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, font

Preciso alterar o formato da fonte e jogar para cima do ícone conforme imagem.
O texto está sendo exibido por: label: beach[7]

```
  for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    var beach = locations[i];
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(beach[5], beach[6]);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        //animation:google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE,  <!-- animação -->
        map: map,
        icon: image,
        shape: shape,
        //title: 'Hello World!',
        label: beach[7],
        //linha abaixo deve ser acrescentada para mostrar a caixa no click
        html: beach[0]+beach[1]+beach[2]+beach[3]+beach[4]
    });
```

[image: preciso que fique acima do veículo]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [propriedades de uma *label*](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#MarkerLabel) no Marker são bem limitadas. Veja abaixo:

```
 - color       string:   Cor do texto
 - fontFamily  string:   Definição equivalente ao font-family do CSS
 - fontSize    string:   Tamanho da fonte equivalente ao font-size do CSS. 
 - fontWeight  string:   Largura da letra equivalente ao font-weight do CSS
 - text        string:   Texto no qual quer que mostre.
```

Exemplo de como usar:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map,
    label: {text: "Placa tal", fontWeight: "bold", fontSize: "20px" }
});
```

Porém tem uma outra opção, que é usar o [MarkerWithLabel for V3](https://github.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/tree/master/markerwithlabel). Faça o download do [*markerwithlabel.js*](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/master/markerwithlabel/src/markerwithlabel.js) para seu projeto. Fazendo isso, basta definir configurar sua *label* via CSS e algumas propriedades no seu `Marker`.

Primeiro passo é substituir seu `new google.maps.Marker` para `new MarkerWithLabel`, desta forma:

```
var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
    //inserir propriedades
});
```

Veja abaixo como seria um exemplo de classe no CSS:

**CSS:**

```
.labelcustom{
    color: #000;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

**JS:**

Dentro do seu Marker, insira o

- `labelContent`: conteúdo da *label*
- `labelAnchor`: posicionamento da *label* em relação ao centro do *marker*
- `labelClass`: definição da classe da *label*

Veja abaixo um exemplo:

```
labelContent: "Placa: MLW-5973",
labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(80, 80),
labelClass: "labelcustom"
```

**Resultado:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

## Bonus:

Veja como eu faria se fosse um projeto meu:

```js
function initMap() {
  var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(49.47805, -123.84716);
  var homeLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(49.47805, -123.84716);

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
    zoom: 12,
    center: latLng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  var image = {
          url: 'https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/67/67994.svg',
          size: new google.maps.Size(40, 40),
          origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
          anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 32)
        };
  var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
    icon: image,
    position: homeLatLng,
    map: map,
    labelContent: "MLW-5973",
    labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(30, 60),
    labelClass: "labels"
  });

  var iw = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: "Home For Sale"
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}

.labels {
  color: #010101;
  background-color: #E3E3E3;
  font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Arial", sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 85px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #010101;
  padding: 2px; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=geometry,places&ext=.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/master/markerwithlabel/src/markerwithlabel.js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas" style="height: 400px; width: 100%;"></div>
```

Comment: consegui resolver de outra forma mais manual, mas deu certo. Para finalizar precisaria deixar em negrito a fonte.
Continuo com o mesmo código anterior.

Comment: @LucasSpielmann Eu uso geralmente este plugin porque é mais fácil de manusear, porque usa CSS. Como neste exemplo que dei, já está em negrito e com uma fonte maior.

Comment: var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: map,
        icon: image,
        shape: shape,
 label: beach[7],
 html: beach[0]+beach[1]+beach[2]+beach[3]+beach[4]
    });

Comment: sumiram os icones

Comment: se não me engano estou usando v2 da API, acho que terei que passar para a v3

Comment: não conseguimos apenas inserir negrito no label: beach[7]?

Comment: Aumentei o tamanho da imagem, isso fez com que o texto decesse. O objetivo era retirado de cima da imagem. Ficou bom, apenas precisaria um negrito para finalizar.

Comment: Tenta assim: `label: {
         text: "Placa tal",
         fontWeight: "bold"
   },`

Comment: Ótimo, e se quiser aumentar a fonte, fontsize: "20" ??

Comment: @LucasSpielmann Boa sorte ai! Só da nós nas madrugadas da vida. =D Viu o bônus que coloquei?!

Comment: Ótimo, o bônus vou estudar com tempo... Kkkk obrigado mais uma vez.

Comment: fontSize:"30" não deu..

Comment: Estou pelo celular editando o fonte KKK amanhã falamos. Boa noite.

Comment: @LucasSpielmann coloque  `fontSize: "20px" ` com o PX de pixel. hueh

Comment: ei amigão, me ajuda nessa:
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/258220/somar-horas-php-e-mysql

Abraço